# Selenium test organisation of classes

Tags: java, class, selenium

Ok selenium gurus a bit of an open question here.  I am looking for some guidance on the best way to organize my tests that use object oriented principles.

At the moment I am creating a testrunner main class from which I create an object of a general test class.  I am then extending this class for more granular tests.

An example.

I need to open the browser, enter the url,  log in as a user.

From there you can access perhaps 40 different links each containing their own pieces of functionality.  E.g. A profile link which leads to a profiule screen where you can enter introduction text, upload a picture, change a picture etc...

Another example would be a notification screen where you can navigate to view and mark as read etc...notifications you have received.

I can write the code to test this by for example by creating a ton of methods in that 1 class and then calling these from the main testrunner class.  There has to be a better organized way where I can have a separate class for functionality but wont I then have to create a new object for each test?

Sorry about the confused post I'm trying to learn Java thoroughly and selenium also.

## EDITED

I have copied the process of creating a page object hybrid model that is documented in the YouTube video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gxwh8D_tx-0

I created a Pages package which contains all of the Page specific class such such ProfilePage, NotificationPage etc...

I have a second package which contains the tests and a testbase class which generates the driver object, opens the browser.

I want to get to the stage where in my tests class I can have a specific class for a test for example:

class test_that_user_can_upload_profile_picture

When I create such a class I have methods inside the class such as: test_that_navigation_to _profile_page_successful()

test_to_upload_valid_picture()

Should such navigation methods be inside this class?

Also I find that in order to access my methods from a package I need to mark my methods as static.  Is this ok?  I noticed on the youtube video the instructors methods were not static.  Looking at the setup I dont quite understand why I cant access the methods unless I mark them as static.  The error i get is 
"Cannot make a static reference to a non-static method"

Here is my setup:
[image: framework]

Also Im finding that in my ProfilePageNavigation class I have a bunch of methods that run in a specific order based alphabetical order.

Is it simply the case I should just have 1 method in each test class and just call the page classes methods(or any other pertinent class) to execute this test? If it is just 1 method inside each test class then wouldnt I have too many test classes each with a name like (for example) upload_valid_profile_picture with a method using the same name? and then another class with upload_invalid_profile_picture with it's method.  I dont want to go down that path - how do I resolve that?

Also all my Pages class methods have to take WebDriver driver as a parameter is there any way around this - it is a lot of duplication.

If you could point me on the right track and let me know in it is ok to have the pages class methods as static it would be appreciated.

I guess I just want to know whether I am on the right track or going down the wrong route at this early stage.

Comment: This question isn't a good fit for SO because it is too open ended. This is more for specific questions around programming and is likely to be closed soon. Having said that... I would suggest that you read up on the page object model. It's about creating one class per page and containing all locators for that page within along with methods that correspond to user actions on that page. For example, a LoginPage would contain locators for the username and password fields, and the login button. It would contain a Login() method that would put the username and password into the fields and log in.

Comment: @JeffC Thank for the comment JeffC  I did in fact do some research on your suggestionbs and am trying to implement that.  I edited my post with a few questions and to make it more specific.

Answer (score -1):

@tarquin - you can find many articles on that @web, There are multiple ways to handle your code and work with it, my way is :

1. Create a objects repository in notepad or excel, from where you can pick/change/manage all your objects.
2. Create a class with all re-usable methods.
3. Create a class of your tests.

Thanks
Keshav

Comment: I modified my post to be more specific.  It would be great if you could take another look at my edited post.

Comment: @tarquin- it seems you are asking us to guide you with creation of full framework, But there are multiple ways by which you can build the same framework i.e. POM in your case. As per my earlier answer you should study on it at web rather than asking here and if you are facing any issues while creating one, we are always here to help you.